# How to use dataprovider for fetching char array

Tags: java, testng, dataprovider

I have a class that has a char array as the input, how can I provide data using dataprovider?

```
@Test
public void testSomething(){
    char[] list = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
    MyArray myArray = new MyArray();
    myArray.doSomething(list);
}
```

I'd like to have a datadriven like this:

```
{
{'a', 'b', 'c'},
{'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};
}
```

The problem is, it will treat the char as individual ones when using 2D array. Therefore, an error of "trying to pass 3 parameters but method takes 1".

please help.
Thank you.

Comment: It would help if you included some relevant code, such as `MyArray`.

Comment: have you tried writing a dataprovider ? please share the code, also what do you mean by the error stated, please clarify.

Answer (score 2):

Inferring from the question details, to use data providers for a set of data types. You can specify your test data as following in a DataProvider class :

```
@DataProvider(name = "testData")
public static Object[][] testData() {
    char[] data1 = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
    char[] data2 = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};
    return new Object[][]{{data1, data2}};
}
```

and consume the same in your test class as :

```
@Test(dataProvider = "testData", dataProviderClass = <ClassName>.class)
public void testSomething(char[] data1, char[] data2){
    MyArray myArray = new MyArray();
    myArray.doSomething(data1);
    myArray.doSomething(data2);
}
```

---

OR alternatively you can create a list/array of `char[] data` and return that from your data provider to iterate(assuming it to

```
@Test(dataProvider = "testData", dataProviderClass = <ClassName>.class)
public void testSomething(List<List<Character>> charData){
    MyArray myArray = new MyArray();
    for(List<Character> dataTypes : charData) {
    myArray.doSomething(dataTypes);
}
```

***Note*** : Her, assuming you have a *correct working* definition of `MyArray`

Comment: This really helps! The second solution is what I wanted. But the compiler complains the data type. And I modified a little bit, but still getting " java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch".   

public class MyArrary(){
 public void doSomething(char[] datalist){
  
 }
}

@Test(dataProvider = "testData", dataProviderClass = <ClassName>.class)
public void testSomething(List<char[]> charData){
    MyArray myArray = new MyArray();
    for(char[] dataTypes : charData) {
        myArray.doSomething(dataTypes);
}

Comment: if there is an error that you might face after modifying something. you shall probably update the question or raise another.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try doing something like this

```
public class DataProviderExample {
    @Test (dataProvider = "dp")
    public void testMethod(Character[] myArray) {
        System.err.println("The input array ways : " + Arrays.toString(myArray));
    }

    @DataProvider (name = "dp")
    public Object[][] getData() {
        return new Object[][] {
            {'t', 'e', 's', 't', 'n', 'g'},
            {'j', 'a', 'v', 'a'}
        };
    }
}
```

This when run generates the below output (which confirms that the test method is indeed receiving a character array )

```
The input array ways : [t, e, s, t, n, g]
The input array ways : [j, a, v, a]

===============================================
Default Suite
Total tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```